# How to dual boot RHEL 6 and Windows 8?

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, grub, rhel-6

**The Situation:**
I have an ASUS Notebook with Windows 8 preinstalled, i created a new partition and installed RHEL 6 to that partition, but the computer keeps booting into Windows 8 without going into grub, even with secure boot disabled.

**What i am trying to achieve**: 
I'd rather have grub showing when i boot and Windows chainloaded, but would set for the Windows 8 bootloader showing my RHEL6.

**WHYT:**
Before everything else i disabled secure boot, then i created a separate partition and happily installed RHEL6 to it.
I tried using the RHEL DVD to go into rescue mode and ran sudo grub-install on /dev/sda.

My partitions currently look like:

1. 300MB (EFI)
2. 600Mb (Recovery)
3. 370Gb (NTFS, Boot,Page File, Crash Dump, Primary)
4. 337Gb (NTFS, Primary)
5. 500Mb (EFI)
6. 200Gb (Primary, RHEL6 default layout)
7. 20Gb (Recovery)

Thanks for the help and let me know if and what other information is required.